# c++ boost spirit attr_cast does not invoke the expected tranform_attribute

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am working on c++ string literal parser with boost spirit.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/support/iterators/line_pos_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_confix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit;

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

////////////////////////////////
// extra facilities
struct get_line_f
{
    template <typename> struct result { typedef size_t type; };
    template <typename It> size_t operator()(It const& pos_iter) const
    {
        return get_line(pos_iter);
    }
};

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits
{
    template <>
    struct transform_attribute<uint16_t, std::string, qi::domain>
    {
        typedef std::string& type;
        static std::string pre(uint16_t& d) { return "pre16"; }
        static void post(uint16_t& val, std::string& attr) { attr = "unicode16"; }
        static void fail(uint16_t&) {}
    };
}}}

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits
{
    template <>
    struct transform_attribute<uint32_t, std::string, qi::domain>
    {
        typedef std::string& type;
        static std::string pre(uint32_t& d) { return "pre32"; }
        static void post(uint32_t& val, std::string& attr) { attr = "unicode32"; }
        static void fail(uint32_t&) {}
    };
}}}

//
////////////////////////////////

struct RangePosition
{
    RangePosition()
        : beginLine(-1)
        , endLine(-1)
    {
    }

    size_t beginLine;
    size_t endLine;
};

struct String : public RangePosition
{
    String()
        : RangePosition()
        , value()
        , source()
    {
    }

    std::string value;
    std::string source;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(String,
                            (std::string, value)
                            (std::string, source)
                            (size_t,      beginLine)
                            (size_t,      endLine)
                          )

template <typename Iterator>
struct source_string : qi::grammar<Iterator, String(), qi::space_type>
{
    struct escape_symbols : qi::symbols<char, char>
    {
        escape_symbols()
        {
            add
                ("\\\'"    , '\'')
                ("\\\""    , '\"')
                ("\\\?"    , '\?')
                ("\\\\"    , '\\')
                ("\\0"     , '\0')
                ("\\a"     , '\a')
                ("\\b"     , '\b')
                ("\\f"     , '\f')
                ("\\n"     , '\n')
                ("\\r"     , '\r')
                ("\\t"     , '\t')
                ("\\v"     , '\v')
            ;
        }

    } escape_symbol;

    source_string() : source_string::base_type(start)
    {
        using qi::raw;
        using qi::_val;
        using qi::_1;
        using qi::space;
        using qi::omit;
        using qi::no_case;
        using qi::attr_cast;
        using qi::print;

        namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
        using phx::at_c;
        using phx::begin;
        using phx::end;
        using phx::construct;
        using phx::ref;

        escape %= escape_symbol;

        character %=   (no_case["\\x"] >> hex12)
                     | ("\\"  >> oct123)
                     | escape
                     | (print - (lit('"') | '\\'));

        unicode %=   ("\\u" >> attr_cast(hex4))
                   | ("\\U" >> attr_cast(hex8));

        string_section %= '"' >> *(unicode | character) >> '"';

        string %= string_section % omit[*space];

        start = raw[
                        string[at_c<0>(_val) = _1]
                   ]
                   [
                       at_c<1>(_val) = construct<std::string>(begin(_1), end(_1)),
                       at_c<2>(_val) = get_line_(begin(_1)),
                       at_c<3>(_val) = get_line_(end(_1))
                   ]
        ;
    }

    boost::phoenix::function<get_line_f> get_line_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, String(), qi::space_type> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> escape;
    qi::uint_parser<char, 16, 1, 2> hex12;
    qi::uint_parser<uint16_t, 16, 4, 4> hex4;
    qi::uint_parser<uint32_t, 16, 8, 8> hex8;
    qi::uint_parser<char,  8, 1, 3> oct123;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> character;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> unicode;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> string_section;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> string;
};
```

and my testing code is

```
std::string str[] =
{
    "\"\\u1234\\U12345678\"",

    "\"te\"\"st\"",
    "\"te\"  \"st\"",
    "\"te\" \n \"st\"",
    "\"\"",
    "\"\\\"\"",
    "\"test\"",
    "\"test\" something",
    "\"\\\'\\\"\\\?\\\\\\a\\b\\f\\n\\r\\t\\v\"",
    "\"\\x61cd\\X3012\\x7z\"",
    "\"\\141cd\\06012\\78\\778\"",
    "\"te",
    "\"te\nst\"",
    "\"test\\\"",
    "\"te\\st\"",
    //
};

typedef line_pos_iterator<std::string::const_iterator> Iterator;

std::ostringstream result;

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]); ++i)
{
    source_string<Iterator> g;
    Iterator iter(str[i].begin());
    Iterator end(str[i].end());

    String string;
    bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, g, qi::space, string);
    if (r)
        result << string.beginLine << "-" << string.endLine << ": " << string.value << " === " << string.source << "\n";
    else
        result << "Parsing failed\n";
}
```

Can somebody help me why in this rule:

```
        unicode %=   ("\\u" >> attr_cast(hex4))
                   | ("\\U" >> attr_cast(hex8));
```

attr_cast does not invoke transform_attribute that I have defined?

```
namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits
{
    template <>
    struct transform_attribute<uint16_t, std::string, qi::domain>
    {
        typedef std::string& type;
        static std::string pre(uint16_t& d) { return "pre16"; }
        static void post(uint16_t& val, std::string& attr) { attr = "unicode16"; }
        static void fail(uint16_t&) {}
    };
}}}

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits
{
    template <>
    struct transform_attribute<uint32_t, std::string, qi::domain>
    {
        typedef std::string& type;
        static std::string pre(uint32_t& d) { return "pre32"; }
        static void post(uint32_t& val, std::string& attr) { attr = "unicode32"; }
        static void fail(uint32_t&) {}
    };
}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Making builtin primitives types behave "strangely" seems like a VeryBadIdea™.

Assuming you just wish to *decode* I suggest a simpler approach using semantic actions, e.g.

- https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json/blob/master/JSON.cpp#L102

  ```
  char_ = +(
          ~encoding::char_(L"\"\\")) [ qi::_val += qi::_1 ] |
             qi::lit(L"\x5C") >> (                    // \ (reverse solidus)
             qi::lit(L"\x22") [ qi::_val += L'"'  ] | // "    quotation mark  U+0022
             qi::lit(L"\x5C") [ qi::_val += L'\\' ] | // \    reverse solidus U+005C
             qi::lit(L"\x2F") [ qi::_val += L'/'  ] | // /    solidus         U+002F
             qi::lit(L"\x62") [ qi::_val += L'\b' ] | // b    backspace       U+0008
             qi::lit(L"\x66") [ qi::_val += L'\f' ] | // f    form feed       U+000C
             qi::lit(L"\x6E") [ qi::_val += L'\n' ] | // n    line feed       U+000A
             qi::lit(L"\x72") [ qi::_val += L'\r' ] | // r    carriage return U+000D
             qi::lit(L"\x74") [ qi::_val += L'\t' ] | // t    tab             U+0009
             qi::lit(L"\x75")                         // uXXXX                U+XXXX
                  >> _4HEXDIG [ qi::_val += qi::_1 ]
  ```

  This appears easily adapted to your use case.

Now if you insist, firstly wrap the types (so you don't "redefine" essential types for Spirit) and secondly, customize the `container insertion` traits, since `std::string` (or rather `std::vector<char>`?) is a container type.

I wouldn't recommend this though. I like to keep things "simple" and the logic in one place. Obviously this is a "funny" thing to say when using a parser generator like Spirit, because *so much* appears to go on "magically" behind the scenes. However, that is the nature of abstraction. I don't think I'd want to "abstract" decoding unicode escapes here: they feel as they belong in the *problem domain*, not the tooling.

Comment: thank you, can you extend your example to show how it will parse \Unnnnnnnn and what if I would like to parse in string not in wstring

Comment: @gsf Oh I apparently linked an old branch, I moved away from wstring pretty quickly there :) My more recent branch [helper functions](https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json/blob/nowide/JSON.cpp#L48) from the [semantic action](https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json/blob/nowide/JSON.cpp#L42). It also uses the same approach for the reverse ([Karma generator](https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json/blob/nowide/JSON.cpp#L183))

Comment: This was the very first thing I tried. For some reason though it was adding not only the value from the function, but the original result as well. I had to omit it, but then when I had more than one characters they start overriding themselves. Are you sure this is actually working?

Comment: @gsf ... of course. If it's adding both then 95% says you used `%=` (auto-rule assignment) where you should have used `=`. The other 5% says you mixed something up in the use of raw iterators :/